# The best design pattern for algorithms with different number of input parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to help my friend with his project and whilst doing that I saw that he has 2 almost similar algorithms implemented.

My first thought was to use Template pattern.

```
public abstract class Template {
    calculate();
    save();
}
```

and so on. However in second algorithm `calculate()` and `save()` need additional parameters. Code inside both methods in both algorithms is duplicating in 90%.

Lets say in first algorithm I need only longitude and in second longitude and latitude.

Thus, the only way to make it with Template pattern is to create some object with longitude and latitude and to pass it in both algorithms. However, I don't like this solution because of this second parameters that will be "null" in the first algorithm.

Maybe I don't see some better, cleaner way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your template but you can pass an object of type Calculator and have calculators that have different number of parameters for example do it like that:

```
public class Template {
    calculate(ICalculator calculator);       
}

interface ICalculator(){
  double calculate();
}
```

Then you can have types of calculators:

```
class OneParameterCalculator implements ICalculator{

 private final double latitude;

 public OneParameterCalculator(double latitude){ this.latitude=latitude; }

 public double calculate(){
 ....
 }
}

class TwoParameterCalculator implements ICalculator{

 private final double latitude;
 private final double longtitude;

public TwoParameterCalculator (double latitude,double longtitude){ this.latitude=latitude; this.longtitude=longtitude; }

 public double calculate(){
 ....
 }
}
```

And then you can use your template instances like:

```
myTemplate.calculate(new OneParameterCalculator(latitudeValue));
```

This way you separate the calculation from the template. And you can improve from there - for example you can share the calculator instead of creating a new instance every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine "Template method" with "Strategy" pattern. Both patterns are concerned about an algorithm by two different point of views: strategy about the ability of exchanging an algorithm at runtime, and template method about flexibilizing the structure of an algorithm.

As for different number of parameters, you can use method overloading/telescoping or use wrapper-class for parameters + Builder pattern.